# how to configure a dispatcher servlet using web.xml with jakarta latest version(6.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

DispatcherClass not found exception while using  jakarta (web.XML)

I tried but got dispatcher class not found exception . Can anybody help me how to configure dispatcher servlet.(spring MVC 6.0) using web.xml while using the jakarta latest version.